# Cannot Publish Azure web app from the Organisation Network

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I can able to perform the Azure MVC web app publishing from external networks but the publishing fails when I do it from company network.Please let me know what network setting restricts the publishing. Please help. Below is the error message:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error   Web deployment task failed.

(Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.

Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.

Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.)

Please let me know if you need more information reg this.

Thanks
AR_

Answer (score 2):

If nothing has changed other than the external/internal network, my guess is that your company has blocked Web Publishing from inside the network.

I would recommend contacting your network team and asking them to unblock port 8172 which is used by Web Deploy.

Comment: Thanks kyle. We will check with network team and update here.